# Fitting a Poisson distribution with lme4 and nlme

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, lme4-nlme

I am now looking for a GLMM, which could fitted a Poisson distribution with a log-link. From what I see until now, **lme4** allow to specify the family and the link function for `lmer()` model, but the `lme()` function in **nlme** package doesn't. Is there another way to specify it in **nlme**?

May we also do it when fitting a non linear mixed models with both pacakges?

Thanks in advance, your help, would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coaxing R to do something, and not about a statistical issue.

Answer (score 11):

You are correct; there is no way to specify the `family` because the **nlme** package is only for *linear* mixed models or *non-linear* mixed models, which assume Gaussian errors. The range of models fitted by **nlme** does *not* include the generalised linear mixed model (GLMM).

That `lmer()` takes a `family` argument is unfortunate, and IIRC, this may have changed in the latest version on CRAN. You are supposed to explicitly call `glmer()` to fit a GLMM now when using the **lme4** package to fit a GLMM. What used to happen is that if you called `lmer()` with argument `family`, it would call `glmer()` for you.

Comment: The `glmmPQL` function from the `MASS` package builds on `lme()`, from the `nlme` package, to allow for GLMMs including Poisson models (but `glmer` is arguably better). `lmer` with `family` specified does still work, but it is deprecated/gives a warning (eventually it will be removed).

Comment: At the moment, I don't know of a simple way to do a GNLMM (generalized non-linear mixed model) within R: I would suggest looking into AD Model Builder (http://admb-project.org)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the clarifications Ben. I'd forgotten about `glmmPQL`.

Comment: Can you not do generalized nonlinear mixed models with gnlmm ?

Comment: @TomWenseleers Yes, I think so, but you'll need to install them yourself as Jim's packages are not on CRAN (assuming we're all [including the OP] talking about the same "non-linear")